# Control yum update packages sequence

Tags: repository, yum

Couldn't find an answer anywhere so I will try here.
Is there a way to tell yum, while running yum update, to update a specific package as the last one?
I am not talking about requires / dependencies, It just needs to be updated after all other packages on the system.

In a nutshell, I manage local repositories in my environment and this particular rpm holds the version for each repository, so by updating it as last I can label the client with that particular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run two `yum` commands. First one excluding the `.rpm` that you don't want to be updated and second, running your usual update.

```
$ yum --exclude="foo*.rpm" update
```

If `foo*.rpm` comes from a particular repository, then during the update, you can disable it using its name. Name of a repository can be found by looking into `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` file or using the command

```
$ yum repolist
```

Then disable the repo and update. Note, this will disable update of all packages coming from this repo.

```
$ yum --disablerepo="nameOfRepo" update
```

Finally, run your usual update

```
$ yum update
```

Comment: I will clarify my question: I need that specific RPM to be updated once all other packages have been updated successfully. So if yum failed to update some packages, that rpm will not be updated.

Comment: Run `command1 && command2`. `&&` will ensure `command2` is run only after a successful exit of `command1`.